# Can multiple values be implicitly converted into an object?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

Is there a way to implicitly convert multiple variables to a class object when passing them into a function? It works with a single variable, but when I try to pass multiple variables, it would not compile.

```
class B {
public:
    B(int x = 20, bool b = false)
    {
        std::cout << x << " " << b << std::endl; 
    }
};

void doSomething(B obj) { }

int main() {
    doSomething(30);
    // doSomething(30,false);  // won't compile
    ...
}
```

prints

> 30 0

I then tried wrapping them in parentheses, and it compiled but it evaluates the comma separated expression beforehand, and thus only passes one value in as an int.

```
    ....
    doSomething((30,true));
}
```

prints

> 1 0

Comment: Try `doSomething({30,true});`.

Comment: The search term for further research is [uniform initialization](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/uniform-initialization-in-c/)

Comment: If this worked, how would you call a function (or overload) with multiple parameters?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn’t compile because you defined a function that requires **one** argument, but then you try to invoke it by passing it **two**. Therefore, the compiler rightly reports an error.

If you enclose the two parameters in parentheses, as you have noticed, the comma expression is evaluated first and then the object is constructed. In practice, it’s as if you had written:

```
doSomething( B( ( 30 , false ) ) )
```

What you can do, therefore, is:

1. Explicitly construct a temporary object:

   `doSomething( B( 30 , false ) );`
2. Or use initialization lists:

   `doSomething( { 30 , false } );`